# Open GL performance on QT

Tags: qt, 3d, qt4, opengl-es-2.0, cg

I am using the QT 4.8 with Open GL ES 2.0 (created my set of shaders etc...)

Running the entire application from within QGraphicsView that owns a QGraphicsScene, I get relatively low fps although I am rendering a simple model (around 30 fps).

The scene render itself is triggered by a timer that fires at 50Hz (that can be changed).
What would be the most time consuming sections to attend in order to improve the frame rate?

Also, I noticed (using gDebugger) that the functions and states associated with the GL_STENCIL_TEST and GL_SCISSOR_TEST are killer consumers here (over 30% of the time goes on that).  Is there anyway to bypass that?

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: Actually it seems that it is strongly connected to it.   It seems that using overlay mechanism as possible by QT is using the GL to do all of its screen operations (makes sense) however the penalty for doing that seems somewhat high (I measure around 20% higher than without this scheme).   All of this is based on the gDebugger data and function usages compared to the same version without overlay.  Thanks for the short and helpful remark.